# How to Reload DataGridView using DataTable.Load(DataReader) without duplicate records

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview, datatable

Can anyone help me on how to avoid getting duplicated output on `DataGridView`. Here is the image [Before change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CyKwY.png) and the image [After add/edit or delete](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bvu0u.png).

Here is the loader for my `DataGridView`:

```
private DataTable data()
{
    using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(inventorydb))
    { 
        using (OleDbCommand com = new OleDbCommand("Select * FROM Items",con))
        {
            con.Open();
            OleDbDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader();
            items.Load(reader);
        }
    }
    return items;
}
void reset()
{
    connect.Close();
    connect.ConnectionString = inventorydb;
    connect.Open();
    dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
    dataGridView1.Update();
    dataGridView1.Refresh();
    dataGridView1.DataSource = data();
}
```

Add and save changes:

```
private void save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (mode == "a")
    {
        connect.Close();
        connect.ConnectionString = inventorydb;
        connect.Open();
        sqlcommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Items (SerialID,        Brand_Name, Item_Name,Item_Date) VALUES ('" + txtserial.Text + "','" + txtbrand.Text + "', '" + txtitem.Text + "', '" + date + "') ";
        sqlcommand.Connection = connect;
        OleDbDataReader reader = sqlcommand.ExecuteReader();
        MessageBox.Show("Record(s) Saved", "Sample");
    }
    connect.Close();
    reset();     
}
```

Comment: use distinct keywords in the querry

Comment: Could you show the code in Add, Edit or Delete? I am unable to reproduce this behavior with the code provided.

Comment: I tried putting in the button for me to save / add items on the access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`DataTable.Load`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.load(v=vs.110).aspx) adds result to the existing rows by default. So if you need to just have latest records, before calling `DataTable.Load`, you should clear the `DataTable`, otherwise the new result will be merged with existing rows.

So with your `items` variable which is `DataTable`, you can use either of these options:

```
items= new DataTable();
```

or

```
items.Clear();
items.AcceptChanges();
```

> [`DataTable.Load`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.load(v=vs.110).aspx)
>
> Fills a `DataTable` with values from a data source using the supplied
>   `IDataReader`. If the `DataTable` already contains rows, the incoming
>   data from the data source is merged with the existing rows.

Comment: Thank you very much. That works perfectly, i can finish my Project now.

Comment: Last question,
On datagridview is there something like this - listView1.FullRowSelect = true; 
So that once they select a content, not only a shell but the full row will be selected, and editing the cells showing on datagrid will be disabled?

Thanks!

Comment: Setting `FullRowSelect` doesn't disable editing. It just enable full row selection. If you have any problem with editing the rows, you may have some other issue, for example probably you set `ReadOnly` to true. If my comment was not helpful, then it's better to ask a new question about the new issue because question should be specific to a single problem.

Comment: Can you help me sir on this part.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39688685/error-syntax-error-every-time-update-or-save-on-data

Comment: I read the question. Fortunately there was a correct answer for the question, I also added a comment to the answer.