# Insert and Update syntax error on Database / Datagrid

Tags: c#, database, ms-access, datagridview, syntax-error

Here is my button command for save.
need help in getting this to work, will be getting this to defend for tomorrow school project. 
Thanks!
Its for Datagridview, access, c#.
I use 2010VS and MS Access 2007.

```
private void save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (adminyes.Checked == true || adminno.Checked == true && textBox1.Text != null && textBox2.Text != null && textBox3.Text != null)
        {
            admin = "Yes";

            if (mode == "a")
            {
                x = 0;
                connect.Close();
                connect.ConnectionString = inventorydb;
                connect.Open();
                sqlcommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Username ='" +textBox2.Text+ "' Or User_ID ='" +textBox1.Text+ "' ";
                sqlcommand.Connection = connect;
                OleDbDataReader reader = sqlcommand.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    x++;
                }

                if (x != 0)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("", "",MessageBoxButtons.OK);
                }
                else
                {
                    DialogResult res = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure?", "Save User", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);

                    if (DialogResult.Yes == res)
                    {
                        connect.Close();
                        connect.ConnectionString = inventorydb;
                        connect.Open();
                        sqlcommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Users (User_ID, Username, Password, Admin) VALUES ('" + textBox1.Text + "','" + textBox2.Text + "', '" + textBox3.Text + "', '" + admin + "') ";
                        sqlcommand.Connection = connect;
                        reader = sqlcommand.ExecuteReader();
                        MessageBox.Show("Record(s) Saved", "Sample");
                    }

                    reset();
                }
            }
            else if (mode == "e")
            {
                DialogResult res = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure?", "Update User", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);

                if (DialogResult.Yes == res)
                {
                    connect.Close();
                    connect.ConnectionString = inventorydb;
                    connect.Open();
                    sqlcommand.CommandText = "UPDATE Users SET User_ID = '" + textBox1.Text + "',  Username = '" + textBox2.Text + "', Password = '" + textBox3.Text + "',Admin = '" + admin + "' WHERE SerialID = '" + idholder + "'  ";
                    sqlcommand.Connection = connect;
                    OleDbDataReader reader = sqlcommand.ExecuteReader();
                    reader.Read();
                    MessageBox.Show("Record(s) Updated", "Sample");

                }

                reset();
            }
        }
        else 
        {
            MessageBox.Show("", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

`Password` is a reserved word in Access.  Change it to `[Password]` in your SQL queries. You should wrap all columns and tables like this.

Although this is just a school project I'll mention a few things:

Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. Here's how to fix this for your insert method as an example:

```
sqlcommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [Users] ([User_ID], [Username], [Password], [Admin]) VALUES (@user_id, @username, @password, @admin)";
sqlcommand.Connection = connect;
sqlcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user_id", textBox1.Text);
sqlcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", textBox2.Text);
sqlcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", textBox3.Text);
sqlcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@admin", admin);
reader = sqlcommand.ExecuteReader();
```

Also passwords shouldn't be stored in plain text. Look into password hashing and salting and how to approach it properly for more information.

Comment: Thank you..!!!

It works, i was trying to figure out on how to protect the password.
I'm not sure how to but really thanks a lot!

Comment: Just a quick question sir, i have a bit of a problem whenever i add/edit/delete items on my data then after i close the program and open it again, all changes i made do not permanently save/reflect on the access database, do you know how to fix it?

Comment: Maybe you need to call `OleDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery` rather than `ExecuteReader`. Also if you have a transaction active (i don't see one though) call `OleDbTransaction.Commit`. If that doesn't work try looking up some sample queries on access databases using `OleDb` objects and see if there are any differences. I'm not too familiar with Access databases.

Comment: If a [reserved word](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Access-2007-reserved-words-and-symbols-e33eb3a9-8baa-4335-9f57-da237c63eabe) is already in use, you can avoid error messages by surrounding each occurrence of the word with brackets ([ ]). However, the best solution is to change the name to a nonreserved word.